# Find maximum deviation in range of %20 between variables

Tags: matlab

How to write a command in Matlab to check the deviation between one variable and others to be within +- %20? as if not in the range would print false if within the range print true

For example, I want to compare R1,R2,R3 with R and should be with the range of plus/minus %20:

```
R = 0.62
R1 = 0.638
R2 = 0.6337
R3 = 0.6354
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want the absolute difference `abs(var1-var2)` to be smaller than some percentage. You compute the percentage by dividing a piece by the total `abs(var1-var2)/var1`. This value must be smaller than 0.2, so `abs(var1-var2)/var1<0.2`

Comment: Noting for OP that if they had used an array for the test cases, your approach also works for a vector `abs(R - [R1,R2,R3])/R < 0.2` with corresponding array output

Comment: Thanks Ander, do you know how to write the command in Matlab to compare these 3 variable with the main R which need to be within minus/plus %20 not only one side...sorry I'm beginner in Matlab

Comment: Thanks Wolfie, I like your approach how to check minus/ plus %20 to print the result either false or true

Comment: @AlexDe If I understand correctly, this answer already takes into account the two sides, because it uses the _absolute_ value of the difference

Comment: @AlexDe Those are MATLAB commands.... Just take Wolfies comment.